# How do I move hover to the following element and then click on the visible button?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is the element I want my mouse to move on. `<div id="div282" class="divAsset">`

On Mouse hover, a few elements would be visible and I want to click on

```
<a class="tileDownloadButton button" title="Download" target="_blank" href="xxxxx"> Download </a>
```

How do I move hover to the following element and then click on the visible button?

Comment: You can use Action class to perform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python

```
asset = driver.find_element_by_id("div282")
action.move_to_element(asset).perform();
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Download')]");
button.click()
```

Java

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("div282"))).perform();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Download')]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute jquery to hover on element.

Example in python.

```
driver.execute_script("$('.classname').trigger('mouseover')")  #selecting element based on classname.
```

Example in Java:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("$('.classname').trigger('mouseover')");
```

This will make the elements visible and then you can easily click on the elements.

see other jquery selectors [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)

Comment: sir, can you please explain ".classname" in example from Java?

Comment: ".classname" is the classname in your html for example : class="tileDownloadButton button" you need to replace ".classname" with ".tileDownloadButton button"

Comment: Thank you sir, appreciate your answer!